# java -Sorting Strings, some kind of

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

Basicly I have two arrays of Strings. One of the String contains a number, the second string contains text and a number.

How can I match these together, please?

Example:

```
private String[] StringArray1 = {"5648", "4216", "3254", "2541", "10"};
private String[] StringArray2 = {"Derp: 10", "Herp: 3254", "peter: 2541", "jdp: 4216", "dieter: 5648"};
```

Output should be:

```
dieter: 5648
jdp: 4216
Herp: 3254
peter: 2541
Derp: 10
```

Well, all I want is to sort StringArray2 for values, so it starts with the highest and I can print it out then.

Comment: Look at String method 'matches(String regex)', then come back with a proposition.

Comment: How about starting with some syntactically-valid code? `String1` and `String2` aren't valid string arrays, nor are they valid strings.

Comment: The question is not explicit enough, there are several ways to interpret it. Start with writing what exactly you want to achieve. Describe your algorithm in several steps in plain English - what would you do with a pen and a paper if you were given the question? Then try to mimic that algorithm in Java - we will gladly help you there.

Comment: updated the main post, to reflect what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
String[] string1 = {"5648", "4216", "3254", "2541", "10"};
String[] string2 = {"Derp: 10", "Herp: 3254", "peter: 2541", "jdp: 4216", "dieter: 5648"};
for (String str : string2)
{
    String[] keyVal = str.split(": ");
    hashMap.put(keyVal[1],keyVal[0]);
}
for (String key : string1)
{
    String val = hashMap.get(key);
    System.out.println(val+": "+key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you convert the second array into MAP then you can easily complete your task.Key will be number and value will be text of array in MAP

Comment: I'm kind of new to java, I haven't used MAP yet :/

Comment: @user3188045 Search on google you will found so many examples.The generic solution will be map

Answer (score 0):

Using the Map is good solution.

for example:

```
Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
data.put("Herp", 3254);
data.put("peter", 2541);
//...

for (String name: data.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(name + ": " + data.get(name) );
}
```

Yes, if this data is your input, collect the map as described in previous answer. But if possible, use the map initially.